# Update Legacy Project from JVM 1.6 to 1.8

Tags: java, maven, jvm

I have to update my legacy project from JVM 1.6 to 1.8. Obviously, I'll need to make some changes like install JVM 1.8 on the server that the code will run.
My project is Java based.

- What tasks do I need to do to accomplish this?
- What risks or complications should I be aware of and plan for?
- I'm using Maven. Do I have to make changes to my pom files?
- do I have to make changes to my startup bash scripts?
- what do I need to do to ensure that the code is compiled under 1.8?

links:

- [Upgrading existing Java Project from Java 1.6 to 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386432/upgrading-existing-java-project-from-java-1-6-to-1-8?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Just compile using jdk 1.8 and check for any warnings about
  deprecated methods.
- Java 8 introduces lots of features like lambda streams..etc, try to enhance your code wherever required. (its not mandatory though)
- Always good to use latest dependencies
- No changes are required to start bash scripts
- Since youare migrating from java 6 to java , you could use try with resource feature which is introduced in java 7.

Try to enhance your code wherever it is applicable. Good luck